# Rendering Material Infront of Sprite URP Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

I'm creating a Chess game in Unity but I have ran into a problem.
I'm trying to render a Material behind the Chess piece, but instead its rendering In front of the piece.

[The Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngyFkyef7x8)

[What I've tried](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGhvvPhJZ7k)

The Material used when I hover my Mouse

[image: The Material used when I hover my Mouse]

The Transparent Material below the Hover Material, when I hover

[image: The Transparent Material below the Hover Material, when I hover]

My URP settings

[image: My URP settings]

All the Chess Pieces are Sprites.
How can I get the Material to render behind the Chess Piece?
Please help I've been stuck wondering for a while now.

I'm expecting the Hover material below the Chess Piece, not above.

Comment: Did you try enabling `Depth` in your Hover Render Feature? In your second video at 0:16 one can see that the hover tile is rendered on top in 3D too. I guess the render pass is not depth testing against the sprites.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try this shortly!

Comment: It did not fix my problem but I did a little more searching and found this thread that fixed it.https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/sg8mco/urp_how_can_i_render_an_object_on_top_of_all/